# When I have three or more modifiers for an object, the middle ones are not showing

Tags: modifiers

As shown in the picture, I miss the middle modifiers. If I apply one of the ones shown, then the next hidden modifier appears.

Anyone ran into the same issue ? Using 2.91.0 but tried up to 2.93 to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Hello this looks like a bug. Please report to there https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports for more information